# Is the ME app from 8.1 still available in Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, tiles

[Under 8.1, I liked the "ME" app](http://mspoweruser.com/windows-phone-8s-me-tile-functionality-has-been-changed-in-windows-phone-8-1/) that put my avatar onto a tile on the Start menu and provided some Social networking functionality.

I upgraded to Windows 10 Mobile, and the tile was missing. Was the ME app removed from Windows 10 Mobile, or is it still available somehow?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **Me Tile** is no longer available in Windows 10 Mobile. Here is the full list of deprecated features:

- Notifications for missed calls, messages and emails on contact tiles is not supported at the time of Windows 10 Mobile release.
- Me Tile and Me Card are no longer supported.
- Cortana can no longer search for apps, settings, email, text messages, contacts and QR Codes on the device and can no longer open apps through voice commands.
- "Hey Cortana" is no longer available on some upgraded devices.
- Group tiles can no longer be used to receive social networking status updates.
- Indoor Maps are no longer available for some locations.
- Certain enterprise features, including Data Protection Under Lock, are not available. Please contact your Microsoft Volume Licensing representative for more information.
- At time of Windows 10 Mobile release Outlook Mail app cannot open .EML attachments.
- The Outlook Calendar app does not support Tasks.
- The MDM functionality to prevent saving and sharing Office documents is not supported.

Source: [Microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-10-specifications?OCID=win10_null_vanity_win10specs#featdeprphone) (select Mobile → Feature deprecation)

Comment: Funny thing is, I still can open apps through Cortana voice commands just fine...

Comment: Thanks for finding that list. It doesn't, however, list all changes, e.g. Microsoft Edge has replaced Internet Explorer and the saving of thumbshots of webpages to tiles (which I really liked) no longer works http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/12774/image-of-webpage-on-tile-in-w10m