# Image of Webpage on Tile in Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, tiles, microsoft-edge

In Windows Phone 8.1, when you used Internet Explorer to go to a website, you could pin the page to the Start menu and the tile would be a thumbshot of the webpage.

[image]

Now it seems that in Windows 10 Mobile, Microsoft Edge (which replaces IE) will save a boring one-color tile with the website name at the bottom and the Edge logo in the middle.

[image]

Previously saved tiles that were on my phone prior to upgrade to Windows 10 Mobile now have just the one-color tile with no logo.

[image]

Has this feature (thumbshot of webpage on the tile) been removed from Windows 10 Mobile/Microsoft Edge Broswer, and if so, is there any other way or are there any apps that will let you use a thumbnail of a website as the tile image?

Comment: It seems that this feature is not yet brought to Edge. Please provide this as a feedback in the feedback app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not yet available in Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 Mobile. 
I'd suggest you upvote this suggestion in the feedback app.

I haven't found a browser app yet, that would support this.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. The problem is not the Windows 10 Mobile, but a failure in the updates. When you do a full factory reset, the thumbshots on the tile are back.

Comment: Really? So now when you now pin a new website in Edge to the start screen, does it give you a thumbshot? Or does it only work for tiles created prior to your Windows Mobile 10 update?